# How to Create a Drop-down Nav Menu With HTML5 and JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

as the title says i want to create Drop-down Navigation Menu With HTML5 and JQuery, and i'm not sure how to do that, any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using HTML5 and jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this tutorial, it should do it

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-create-a-drop-down-nav-menu-with-html5-css3-and-jquery/

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)